# How do i get log output from Node.Js app runnng on Azure App Service Linux?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, nuxt.js

I'm running a express.js app (starting a Nuxt application) on a Azure App Service on Linux and are getting a application error when requesting some pages.

How do I get the console output from node in Azure on Linux? None of the logs provided seems to give me the node trace and console log output so how can I troubleshoot the error?

My `server.js` looks like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const {Nuxt} = require('nuxt')


const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
// Import and set Nuxt.js options
let config = require('./nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = false;
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)
// Give Nuxt middleware to express
app.use(nuxt.render)
// Listen the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server listening on :' + port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to this url:
https://[project-name].scm.azurewebsites.net/
This url is linked in your Azure App Services project under "Advanced Tools".

There is a Link to the current Docker logs.
In this file you can find errors related to nodejs and express.

Comment: But this doesn't tell me anything... it only says: 2018-10-16 05:27:48.733 INFO  - Starting container for site
2018-10-16 05:27:48.733 INFO  - docker run -d -p 1111:8080 --name x_0 -e WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=8.11 -e APPSETTING_WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=8.11 -e WEBSITES_PORT=3000 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=x -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=x -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/node:8.11.2_1805212105 $NPM_CMD run build; $NPM_CMD start